# How to call jquery.min.js file in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-thesis-theme

I am just trying to implementing Dropdown in wordpress home page so that I could  select country and after then second dropdown will get enable and as well third

But the issue is that I am running that locally successfully using html and  javascript but don't know how to implement it with wordpress I have successfully made drop down but its javascript is not working.

```
<html>
<head>
<script 
src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"> 
</script>   
</head>
<body>
<div class="combotitle">Size</div>
<form>
 <select id="Size" name="Size" class="criterion">
    <option value="">Select a size</option>
    <option value="1">Size 1</option>
    <option value="2">Size 2</option>
    <option value="3">Size 3</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <div class="combotitle">Style</div>
    <form>
    <select id="Style" name="Style" class="criterion">
    <option value="">Select a Style</option>
    <option value="1">Style 1</option>
    <option value="2">Style 2</option>
    <option value="3">Style 3</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <div class="combotitle">Color</div>
    <form>
    <select id="Color" name="Color" class="criterion">
    <option value="">Select a Color</option>
    <option value="1">Color 1</option>
    <option value="2">Color 2</option>
    <option value="3">Color 3</option>
    </select>
    </form>

    <div class="combotitle">Brand</div>
    <form>
   <select id="Brand" name="Brand" class="criterion">
    <option value="">Select a Brand</option>
    <option value="1">Brand</option>
    <option value="2">Brand</option>
    <option value="3">Brand</option>
    </select>
    </form>
<div class="CatsearchButton">
    <a href="#"><img src="/searchprd.png" alt="Search" title="Search" /></a>
    </div>

    <script>
   `$('.CatsearchButton').hide();`


 var $selects = $('select.criterion');
 $selects.not("#Brand").on('change', function() {
 $selects.each(function() {
 var $this = $(this);
 var disable = $this.val() == '';
 $this.closest('form').nextAll().find('select').prop('disabled', disable);
 if (disable) return false;
 })
`}).eq(0).trigger('change');
 $selects.filter('#Brand').change(function() {
 $('.CatsearchButton').show();
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function enqueue_multiple() {
    wp_enqueue_script( array( 'jquery') );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_multiple' );
```

you need to put this in your functions.php file of your theme.. read more about theming on https://developer.wordpress.org/